# Como colcocar botão de 'comprar' abaixo do produto no woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

Estou fazendo um ecommerce com o woocommerce para wordpress.

Gostaria de saber como e em que arquivo colocar um botão de "comprar", onde ao clica-lo ele não add ao carrinho, mas sim direcione a pagina do produto. ( o tema não disponibiliza essa opção, por isso que tem que ser feito na mão

Comment: http://chrislema.com/improving-the-woocommerce-add-to-cart-button/

Answer (score 2):

Os ficheiros do woocommerce relativos à apresentação de conteúdos (templates) estão na pasta

> /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/

Nessa pasta pode ver os templates base (entre outros):

> archive-product.php - apresenta uma lista de produtos
>
> single-product.php - detalhes de um produto

Esse ficheiro single-product vai buscar os dados à pasta */single-product*... é nessa pasta que pode fazer as modificações na página do produto... ainda nesta pasta pode ver a sub-pasta */add-to-cart* onde tem os modelos para o botão.

Quanto a mudar o comportamento do botão não sei como será, mas é possível!

**Outra coisa importante**, não modifique os ficheiros aqui, copie-os para a pasta do seu tema de maneira a que fique assim: *.../o_seu_tema/woocommerce/templates/...* e depois modifique esses ficheiros no seu tema! Se os modificar na pasta do plugin vai ficar sem essas modificações quando atualizar o woocommerce!

Answer (score 0):

Para alterar o link do botão teremos que editar o arquivo functions.php localizado em wordpress/wp-content/themes/"seu tema em uso"/

```
function custom_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
return '<a href="LINK PARA PAGINA DE DESTINO" class="button">' . __( 'Comprar' ) . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'custom_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
```

Abra o arquivo citado acima no editor de texto de sua preferência e copie esse código. Troque o "LINK PARA PÁGINA DE DESTINO" pelo link da página que você deseja redirecionar o botão e salve.